# ImageView Camera preview

Tags: android, camera, imageview, preview

Can I set an ImageView to a camerapreview? Instead of using a surfaceview? I'm trying to make a camera preview semi transparent with setAlpha method, but It doesn't work on surfaceview. I mean it does work, but the camera preview is not semi transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you can but not using SurfaceView. You achieve this by using GLSurface view, where you render each of your frame using shaders. In the fragment shader you can specify the opacity of your video. If you don't know OpenGL ES 2.0 you can start from here http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html, but there are also many tutorial including rendering frames using opengl.

Comment: I'm struggling with rendering camera preview using opengl

Comment: When I have a bit of spear time I will post an example

Comment: there is no need for a glsurfaceview. In the end I have taken the yuv from camera preview, convert it into a bitmap, and used a simple imageview.setImageBitmap. https://github.com/Heixss/TransparentScreen

Comment: Heixss.your given link is dead.but i did same as you say in your comment.i set SurfaceView Bitmap into imageView its working fine.but i want to set a Live Camera preview in imageVIew..Please help me if anyone knows....THANK's

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this, SurfaceView is the only way to create a Camera preview in Android.